# Python не видит текст и иногда площадь фигуры

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Дана фотка, нужно определить площадь фигуры и определить цифры. Фигуру находит (но не всегда) и цифры находит и тоже не всегда и иногда он не может определить цифру, например в данном примере он не может прочитать цифру 6, а например цифру 3 он меняет на букву з. 
Вот к примеру фото, где он уже обработал и нашёл всё
[image: Скрин работы]

1. Это площадь (он в этом случае нашёл)
2. Это верхние правые цифры, в данном случае "5/6"
3. Это центральные цифры "7,2"

Как можно по фиксить это? есть какие то рекомендуемые размеры фотографии? Обычно он не находит почти ничего на изображении 1653x2338! А так же может есть какие то нормы для лучшего сканирование цифр? к примеру писать печатными цифрами, типо DS-Digital шрифта (только не полосками)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import imutils
import cv2
import collections
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

hsv_min = np.array((0, 54, 5), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((187, 255, 253), np.uint8)
put = "C:\\45\\tqtt.jpg"
img = cv.imread(put)
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV )

thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max )
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 231), 2, cv.LINE_AA, hierarchy, 2)
cv.imshow('contours', img)
cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv.LINE_AA, hierarchy, 1)
ss = cv.contourArea(contours[0])
print(ss/37.938105)
#----________-----------------------
while True:
    ch = cv2.waitKey()
    if ch == 27:
        break
    if ch == ord('f'):
      pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

       #img = Image.open(put).crop((804, 540, 1120, 580))
      text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='rus',  config='--psm 11')
      print(text)
   # img.show()
   # update()
#------------________---------------
cv.imshow('All_con', img)
cv.imshow('thresh', thresh)

cv.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту задачу следующим способом..

- я дополнил `img = cv.imread(put,-11)`
- Так же нашёл оптимальный кфг - `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='rus',  config='--psm 4')` (если у вас такая же проблема, то нужно играться самим с этим, отличия зависит от разрешения).
- Далее текст читает в основном только шрифтом похожим на  **Consolas**, другие пробовал, ничего не срабатывало.
- Далее как и следовало знать, что на 1653x2338 разрешение находить площадь очень сложно программе, ибо в моем случае маркер не новый и оставляет чуть просветы... Я это исправил тем, что меняю разрешение картинки на 600х825 (вот на столько мало, зато грязи и пробелов больше нету). Находит площадь на раз... В моём случае делаем дубликать картинки и вырезаем верхнию часть (1/2 от изображения).
- Если текст всё равно с трудом видится, то сделайте интервал между буквами (и символами) примерно 1.5-2.5 см. Дело в том, что Tesseract делает боксы на каждом объекте в изображении, и получается так, что блок на блок залезает и из-за этого у вас разные символы получаются, типо "13" он видит "4з" и т.д.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил как это можно исправить. Я всё испытывал около недели и другого варианта не наблюдалось

Comment: Так же, можно создать свой шрифт и научить Pytesseract своим шрифтом например языком ZZZZ и ввести это в код `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='ZZZZ',  config='--psm 4')`